# Getting a blank list of options using ComboBox in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have created a card search for a card game using a `ComboBox` in an `AnchorPane`. 
First I created some card objects who have fields like name,type,image,etc and added them to an `ObservableList` and added the `ObservableList` to a `ComboBox`.
When I click on the `ComboBox` I get a blank list of options to choose from. Selecting a blank option does display the respective card fields in my `AnchorPane` however.

Here is my code:

Card class:

```
public class Card {
    //Enum classes
    public enum Type {

        SPELL("Spell"),
        CREATURE("Creature"),
        EVOLUTION_CREATURE("Evolution Creature")

        //Private fields
        private final String typeValue;

        //Constructor
        private Type(String typeValue){
            this.typeValue = typeValue;
        }

        //Public Methods
        public String getType(){
            return typeValue;
        }
    }

    public enum Civilisation {
        FIRE("Fire"),
        WATER("Water"),
        LIGHT("Light"),
        DARKNESS("Darkness"),
        NATURE("Nature");

        private final String civilisationText;

        private Civilisation(String civilisationText)
        {
            this.civilisationText = civilisationText;
        }

        public String getCivilisation(){
            return civilisationText;
        }
    }

    public enum Cost {
        ONE(1),
        TWO(2),
        THREE(3),
        FOUR(4),
        FIVE(5),
        SIX(6),
        SEVEN(7),
        EIGHT(8),
        NINE(9),
        TEN(10);

        private final int cost;

        Cost(int cost){
            this.cost = cost;
        }

        int getCost(){
            return cost;
        }

    }

    public final String type;
    public final String civilisation;
    public final int cost;
    public final String name;
    public final String imageurl;
    //public final Path path;

    //Constructor
    public Card(Type type,Civilisation civilisation,Cost cost,String name,String imageurl) {

        this.type = type.getType();
        this.civilisation = civilisation.getCivilisation();
        this.cost = cost.getCost();
        this.name = name;
        //path = Paths.get(imageurl);
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getCivilisation() {
        return civilisation;
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getImageurl() {
        return imageurl;
    }   
}
```

This is the Controller:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    public MainController() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @FXML
    public ComboBox<Card> combobox;

    @FXML
    public Label name;
    @FXML
    public Label type;
    @FXML
    public Label civilisation;
    @FXML
    public Label cost;

    @FXML
    ImageView imageView;

    Card Aqua_Marine = new Card(Type.CREATURE,Civilisation.WATER,Cost.TWO, "Aqua Marine", "/resources/images/Aqua Marine.jpg");
    Card Aqua_Knight = new Card(Type.CREATURE,Civilisation.WATER,Cost.THREE, "Aqua Knight", "/resources/images/Aqua Knight.jpg");
    Card Death_Knight = new Card(Type.CREATURE,Civilisation.DARKNESS,Cost.SIX, "Death Knight", "/resources/images/Death Knight.jpg");
    Card Terror_Pit = new Card(Type.SPELL,Civilisation.DARKNESS,Cost.SIX, "Terror Pit", "/resources/images/Terror Pit.jpg");


    ObservableList<Card> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Aqua_Marine,Aqua_Knight,Death_Knight,Terror_Pit);

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


        combobox.setItems(list);


    }

    public void comboData(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {

        Card card = combobox.getValue();
        name.setText("Name: "+card.name);
        type.setText("Type: "+card.type);
        civilisation.setText("Civilisation: "+card.civilisation);
        cost.setText("Cost: "+Integer.toString(card.cost));
        Image img = new Image(getClass().getResource(card.imageurl).toURI().toString());
        imageView.setImage(img);
    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of the blank list I am getting:
https://pasteboard.co/HfQ1cKi.png

How can I make the `ComboBox` display the object names or more preferably the field name of each objects?

Also, instead of creating card objects in the Controller class where should I save them?

Comment: Have you set the `cellFactory` or `converter` or removed an override of the `toString` method form the code of the `Card` class you use?

Comment: I tried overriding toString but it didnt work. I have not tried cellFactory or converter. I did a work around and made it work by creating an ArrayList of String containing the card names and making an ObservableList from it but now the problem is getValue() returns a String object but I need Card object for my method comboData. I will go through cellFactory and converter and let you know the results asap.